# How to use ContainsAll in MongoDB

Tags: .net, linq, mongodb

Help me understand why the statement:

```
var query =
collection.AsQueryable<C>()
.Where(c => c.A.ContainsAll(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
```

results in this error:

```
int does not contain a definition for ContainsAll and the best extension method overload MongoDB.Driver.Linq.LinqToMongo.ContainsAll<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)
```

Comment: Can you show us your class definition for C? It looks like the A property is of type int and type int does not define a ContainsAll method. Did you mean for A to be of type int[]?

Comment: You can send me an example of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(x => Query.All("Field", array).Inject())
```